# Find an equation of the tangent line to the circle $(x-3)^2+(y-5)^2=5$ at $P(4,7).$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

What is an equation of the tangent line to the circle $(x-3)^2+(y-5)^2=5$ at $P(4,7)$ ?

What I've found:

1. Center of the circle : $(3,5)$
2. Radius : $\sqrt5$

The equation will be in $y=mx+b$ format, therefore I need to find the slope and $y$-intercept, is it correct?
How can I find the slope and the intercept?

Comment: I think I found the answer. y=-1/2x+13/2 is it right?

Comment: please edit the question to show your work / steps so we can check.

Comment: @hanzo The slope (gradient) is right but the intercept is not. You can see your solution is not correct by putting in $x=4$. You would expect $y=7$ but you don't get that. Show your detailed working.

Comment: $(x+4-3)^2+(y+7-5)^2=5$ reduces to $x^2+2x+y^2+4x=0$ i.e. the tangent line is $2(x-4)+4(y-7)=0.$

Comment: We have a Latex-like typesetting system for mathematical expressions, called MathJax. Information is here:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10164

Comment: I watched a youtube video about it and did some work like this: since the slope is -1/2, I put it into the y=mx+b form. y=-1/2x+b so I put x=3, y=5 to figure out the y-intercept, which is b=13/2.

Comment: @hanzo $(x,y) = (3,5)$ is the centre of the circle, not the point of tangency.

Comment: @peterwhy I see. Does it mean that I should put P(4,7)? Then it gives an equation of y=-1/2x+9, right?

Comment: Yes, you are finding the tangent line at $ \ (4,7) \ \ , $ so you want $ \ y - 7 \ = \ -\frac12·(x-4) \ \ . $ So you have it now.

Answer (score 3):

The centre C is (3,5). The tangent line is perpendicular to the line passing through the centre and the point of tangency. Hence the slope of tangent will be the negative reciprocal of slope of CP. The tangent passes through point P so you get the value of it's y-intercept.

Comment: If you think a post answers your question, you can click on the tick sign just below the downvote sign ....it gives you credit.